# Connection to MS SQL 2005 Database Provides Different Access for Different Users

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I've written an application in C# which connects to a MS SQL 2005 database and executes 3 stored procedures (2 selects, 1 insert). In the connection string I have specified "Integrated Security = false" and included a SQL Server User ID and Password. I am able to connect fine and run all 3 stored procedures just fine as can others who are Admins on the database but users who are not Admin are only able to execute the 2 selects but not the insert. Since the application is connecting using a designated SQL Server application login why is there a difference?

Comment: If you have access to it, one good way to get a better idea of what's going on is to use SQL Profiler to see what commands are actually being sent from your application to the server, and in what context they're being executed.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Does the SQL Server user id that you are using have execute permissions for the insert stored proc?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I took his question to mean that the user id and password are hard-coded into his application. Hopefully the OP will correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yes the User ID and Password are included in the connection string in the application. Also the User ID has execute permission on the stored procedures as well as Select, Insert, Update and Delete on the table. The SQL Server logs show a successful log in using the User ID specified.

Comment: @JeffRosenberg: Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: Can you share your SQL and C# code?

Comment: connection string = 'Data Source=XYZ;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=False;User ID=DBTOOLS;Password=s4df55f'

Comment: We're going to need more than that. The problem isn't likely to be with your connection string, it's something in your code that's causing a procedure to be executed in a different scope.

Comment: The offending Sp is pretty simple -
`USE [DBName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[DBTools_AddException] (@Store varchar(50), @Date varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 BEGIN TRY
  Insert into MissingTrans_Exceptions(Store, Date)
  Select @Store, @Date
  where not exists ( select * from MissingTrans_Exceptions where Store = @Store and Date = @Date)
  SET @cntRow = @@ROWCOUNT
  Select @cntRow as 'Count'
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
  Raiserror('MissingTrans_Exceptions Error - No row updated',16,1)
 END CATCH
END`

Comment: It won't be the SP, it will be the code that calls it. Also, what do you mean when you say "only able to execute the 2 selects but not the insert". What exactly happens when the non-admin  users try to execute the Insert stored procedure? Please  post the full exception (`ex.ToString()`).

Comment: The C# code was built using Visual Studios dataSet designer which forms the database connection using a wizard and creates a strongly typed dataset based on the stored procedure selected. The SQL Server logs show the connection being made correctly using the specified application login as expected so I'm not sure how SQL Server is aware of who the actual user is.